# Extend a div horizontally into a container

Tags: html, css

I have some css and html that I am trying to modify, to make it so a div expands horizontally into a scollable div, but all I get is "stacking" once the width is reached.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cWpGS/46/)

The absolute positioning is pretty important in the document structure, so I will need to keep most of the css as it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: making div extend horizontally requires javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add  `white-space:nowrap;` in "mli" class

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cWpGS/51/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the text is extending fully into the container.  Your problem was that the container only extended to the end of its parent div, which had a very small width assigned.  Changing the width of the container div makes the text not wrap as much:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/cWpGS/47/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I need the widths as they are...is there no way to make the contents of the "mli" class spill over into its parent "q-d-list"? I thought the scrollable property on "q-d-list" would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will make sense

```
.q-d-list-container {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    right:5px;
    bottom:5px;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    border:1px solid #C4C4C4;
}

#q-d-list {
    display:block;
    background:white;
    border:1px solid #D4D4D4;
    width: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:5px;
    bottom:5px;    
    overflow : auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.mli {
    padding:4px 0 4px 6px;
    margin:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}​
```

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/cWpGS/50/)